# Add user input on buttonclick

Tags: android, listview

i'm very new to android studio and don't really know what i'm doing. I'm trying to add items to an listview, but the app crashes when i try to go to the second page. (the app have two pages, no crashes occurred when the second page "was empty".)

Below is my XML.

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list1"
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="373dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/laggtill"
    android:layout_width="340dp"
    android:layout_height="54dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:hint="@string/Sida2Hint"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/list1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.133" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/addButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="@string/Sida2Add"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.942"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.143" />
```

And below is my java class.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class sida2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button btnAdd;
    private EditText et;
    private ListView lv;

    ArrayList<String> Uppgifter = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sida2);

        btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addButton);
        btnAdd.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);
        et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.laggtill);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, R.id.list1);

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        String input = et.getText().toString();
        if (input.length() > 0) {
            // add string to the adapter, not the listview
            adapter.add(input);
            // no need to call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); as it is done by the adapter.add() method
        }
    }
}
```

When i try to go to the "second page" the app just crashes. I have no errors in the studio and i don't really know what to do. Thankful for any help!

Answer (score 0):

[image]    public class sida2 extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

```
    private Button btnAdd;
    private EditText et;
    private ListView lv;

    ArrayList<String> Uppgifter = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addButton);
        btnAdd.setOnClickListener(this);
        et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.laggtill);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, Uppgifter);

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        String input = et.getText().toString();
        if (input.length() > 0) {
            // add string to the adapter, not the listview
            Uppgifter.add(input);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            // no need to call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); as it is done by the adapter.add() method
        }

    }
}
```

//xml

```
[![<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list1"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="373dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/laggtill"
        android:layout_width="340dp"
        android:layout_height="54dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:hint="aaaa"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/list1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.133" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="aaa"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.942"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.143" />

</LinearLayout>][1]][1]
```

PS: Try to debug your app..you will learn a lot. :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the app doesn't crash anymore but now it just closes down instead. :(

Comment: No, i'm sorry it still doesn't work for me.
Could it be that the previous page is interfering with the next one so to speak? 

https://ibb.co/i21tHd